# Java: Hibiscus Walk Hotel & Spa Software Development Project

Tags: java, swing

I have some problems here. I want the program to give me my total bill when I press N but it keeps asking the same question over and over again. When I press Y, it gives basically does the same thing again.

Also, how can I show the amount of change the person should get back? Example: If the 2 items cost $5 and the person pays $10, I would like it to say Your change is $5.

Thank you.

```
String temp = null;
temp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter The amount of Items :");
int Size = Integer.parseInt(temp);
String[] ItemName = new String[Size];
Integer[] ItemId = new Integer[Size];
Double[] ItemPrice = new Double[Size];
Integer index = 0;

while (index < Size) {
  ItemName[index] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter The Item Name:");
  temp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Item ID for " + ItemName[index] + " :");
  ItemId[index] = Integer.parseInt(temp);
  temp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter The Price " + ItemName[index] + " :");
  ItemPrice[index] = Double.parseDouble(temp);
  index++;
}
for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
  System.out.printf("%s\t %d\t %.2f\t\n", ItemName[i], ItemId[i], ItemPrice[i]);
}

surName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your surname");

number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the Amount Paid: ");
amountPaid = Double.parseDouble(number);

System.out.println("Your surname is " + surName);
System.out.print("Enter the Item ID for the item");
compare = keyboard.nextInt();
while (Complete == false) {
  while (a < Size) {
    if (compare == ItemId[a]) {
      Price = Price + ItemPrice[a];
    }
    a++;
  }
  System.out.print("Sale Complete? Enter Y or N");
  response = keyboard.next();

  if (response == "Y") {
    System.out.println("The toal bill is" + Price);
  } else {
    System.out.print("Please answer the following: ");
  }
}
```

Comment: Fix your question title plz.

Comment: Also, you never set `Complete` to `true`.

Comment: So how do I stop the question from repeating ?